# libgdx set position of enemy/monster on the map not in camera view

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm struggling to set up monster on the map, but all I get is placing it on the camera coordinate. I tried to use Tiled and finally I set up monster where I wanted, but I don't know how to move this monster.

[Link to game map, the dragon in right bottom corner is from Enemy class, and the goblin is from Bot class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYUZJ.png)

Here same code from Enemy class

```
public Enemy() {
    img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(path));
    sprite = new Sprite(img);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    position = new Vector2();
}

public void update(float delta) {
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, position.x, position.y);
    batch.end();
}
```

And the Bot class, where I get monster from Tiled

```
public Bot(TextureMapObjectRenderer tiledMapRenderer, String name) {
    this.tiledMapRenderer = tiledMapRenderer;
    try {
        monsterLayer = tiledMapRenderer.getMap().getLayers().get("monster");
        monsterObjects = monsterLayer.getObjects();
        monster = monsterObjects.get(name);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}

public void update(float delta) {
    tiledMapRenderer.renderObject(monster);

}
```

Comment: On a sidenote, make sure you don't publish content using in all likelihood copyrighted sprites. Those do remind me very closely of other games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use TextureMapObject to get X and Y position of the enemy/monster. Also I create method to render MapObject.

```
public void renderMonster(MapObject object) {
    if (object instanceof TextureMapObject) {
        TextureMapObject textureMonster = (TextureMapObject) object;
        textureMonsters.add(textureMonster);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(textureMonster.getTextureRegion(), textureMonster.getX(), textureMonster.getY());
        batch.end();
        // move the monster
        textureMonster.setX(randomMove(-1, 1).x + textureMonster.getX());
        textureMonster.setY(randomMove(-1, 1).y + textureMonster.getY());
    }
}
```

I know that this method is not prefect, but it works.